# Change dataframe pandas based one series

Tags: python, pandas

I have data and have convert using dataframe pandas :

```
import pandas as pd
d = [
  (1,70399,0.988375133622),
  (1,33919,0.981573492596),
  (1,62461,0.981426807114),
  (579,1,0.983018778374),
  (745,1,0.995580488899),
  (834,1,0.980942505189)
]
df_new = pd.DataFrame(e, columns=['source_target']).sort_values(['source_target'], ascending=[True])
```

and i need build series for mapping column `source` and `target` into another

```
e = []
for x in d:
  e.append(x[0])
  e.append(x[1])

e = list(set(e))
df_new = pd.DataFrame(e, columns=['source_target'])

df_new.source_target = (df_new.source_target.diff() != 0).cumsum() - 1
new_ser = pd.Series(df_new.source_target.values, index=new_source_old).drop_duplicates()
```

so i get series :

```
source_target
1        0
579      1
745      2
834      3
33919    4
62461    5
70399    6
dtype: int64
```

i have tried change dataframe `df_beda` based on `new_ser` series using :

```
df_beda.target = df_beda.target.mask(df_beda.target.isin(new_ser), df_beda.target.map(new_ser)).astype(int)
df_beda.source = df_beda.source.mask(df_beda.source.isin(new_ser), df_beda.source.map(new_ser)).astype(int)
```

but result is :

```
   source  target    weight
0       0   70399  0.988375
1       0   33919  0.981573
2       0   62461  0.981427
3     579       0  0.983019
4     745       0  0.995580
5     834       0  0.980943
```

it's wrong, ideal result is :

```
   source  target    weight
0       0       6  0.988375
1       0       4  0.981573
2       0       5  0.981427
3       1       0  0.983019
4       2       0  0.995580
5       3       0  0.980943
```

maybe anyone can help me for show where my mistake

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the order doesn't matter, you can do the following. Avoid `for` loop unless it's absolutely necessary.

```
uniq_vals = np.unique(df_beda[['source','target']])
map_dict = dict(zip(uniq_vals, xrange(len(uniq_vals))))
df_beda[['source','target']] = df_beda[['source','target']].replace(map_dict)

print df_beda

   source  target    weight
0       0       6  0.988375
1       0       4  0.981573
2       0       5  0.981427
3       1       0  0.983019
4       2       0  0.995580
5       3       0  0.980943
```

If you want to roll back, you can create an inverse map from the original one, because it is guaranteed to be 1-to-1 mapping.

```
inverse_map = {v:k for k,v in map_dict.iteritems()}
df_beda[['source','target']] = df_beda[['source','target']].replace(inverse_map)
print df_beda

   source  target    weight
0       1   70399  0.988375
1       1   33919  0.981573
2       1   62461  0.981427
3     579       1  0.983019
4     745       1  0.995580
5     834       1  0.980943
```

Comment: Hi @Happy001, it's not using series right ? if i want to roll back from your result into original value, how can do that ?

Comment: @ihsansat, No I'm not using series. But Series and `dict` should work similar. See edit for rolling back.

Comment: I mean -- if you do `df_beda[['source','target']].map(new_ser)`, it should work similarly, but creating the series by for loop is expensive when dataframe is big.